# Trello - get permanent developer key and verification code

Tags: trello

I can use temporary token, but cannot get permanent key !!!

It showing me this:

> To complete the process, please give this verification code:
>   237963d7359aa898763a615e972d20ea

Question is: where I should input this verification number ????

Thank you!

Comment: Once you get the permanent token from the user, you can insert it in to https://api.trello.com/1/board/substitutewiththeboardid?key=substitutewithyourapplicationkey&token=substitutethispartwiththeauthorizationtokenthatyougotfromtheuser to have permanent read/write access to that private board.

Answer (score 4):

To do this,

First go to this url:

https://trello.com/1/authorize?key=**237963d7359aa898763a615e972d20ea**&name=**MYAPPNAME**&expiration=**never**&response_type=token&scope=read,write

Its going to return a token which does not expire, 
something like this:**c6b832fb7101sdkjfsdkjfhsdmnfsmdnfsdmnf9d5fe53f3d8asdasdee**

Then if you are using [manatee.trello](https://bitbucket.org/gregsdennis/manatee.trello) as a wrapper, you use the returned value as the token.

```
 ManateeSerializer serializer = new ManateeSerializer();
 TrelloConfiguration.Serializer = serializer;
 TrelloConfiguration.Deserializer = serializer;
 TrelloConfiguration.JsonFactory = new ManateeFactory();
 TrelloConfiguration.RestClientProvider = new RestSharpClientProvider();
 TrelloAuthorization.Default.AppKey = "237963d7359aa898763a615e972d20ea";
 TrelloAuthorization.Default.UserToken = "c6b832fb7101sdkjfsdkjfhsdmnfsmdnfsdmnf9d5fe53f3d8asdasdee";
```

Comment: i see you have the string "never" with double * around it in your example URL i'm assuming that i take out the double-stars and it works.

Comment: nvm found it [in their docs](https://developers.trello.com/authorize) "never" gets you an non-expiring key.